# Null reference error in App.xaml MVVM light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I'll make a WPF application whit one window and by changing the content of the `Frame` I'll navigate troth my application. For this I'm using MVVM light.

But on `App.xaml` I've got this error in the error list of Visual Studio.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code where the error happens:

```xml
<Application 
    x:Class="Project.App" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project" 
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    d1p1:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModel"
    xmlns:services="clr-namespace:Project.Services"
    xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <services:IocContainer x:Key="ioc" />
            <vm:ApplicationViewModel x:Key="appvm" d:IsDataSource="True" /> <!-- error happens on this line -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is my `MainWindow`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{StaticResource appvm}"
        Title="Project" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Frame>
        <Frame.Content>
            <Page Content="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>
</Window>
```

Here is my `ApplicationViewModel` that inherits from `ViewModelBase`:

```cs
public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Page _currentPage = IocContainer.Ioc.StartScreenPage;

    public Page CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentPage != value)
            {
                _currentPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public StartScreenViewModel StartScreenViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (App.Current.Resources["ioc"] as IocContainer)?.StartScreenViewModel;
        }
    }

    public void Navigate(Type sourcePageType)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the `ViewModelBase` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```cs
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Debug.WriteLine("PropertyChanged is niet null ☺");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("PropertyChanged is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my IoC container:

```cs
public class IocContainer
{
    static IocContainer()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ApplicationViewModel>(false);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<StartScreenViewModel>(false);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<StartScreenPage>(false);
    }

    public static IocContainer Ioc
    {
        get { return App.Current.Resources["ioc"] as IocContainer; }
    }

    public ApplicationViewModel ApplicationViewModel
    {
        get { return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ApplicationViewModel>(); }
    }

    public StartScreenPage StartScreenPage
    {
        get { return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<StartScreenPage>(); }
    }

    public StartScreenViewModel StartScreenViewModel
    {
        get { return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<StartScreenViewModel>(); }
    }
}
```

Here is my `StartScreenPage`:

```xml
<Page x:Class="Project.StartScreenPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      DataContext="{Binding StartScreenViewModel, Source={StaticResource ioc}}"
      Title="StartScreen">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Hello world" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here is `StartScreenViewModel`.

```cs
public class StartScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase
{ }
```

All the application, window and pages have a default constructor that calls `InitializeComponent`.

I can run my application but I see an empty window.

Did I forgot anything?

**Edit:** Continuing on my anwser on this question: [`Page` can have only `Frame` as parent and not `Window`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018287/page-can-have-only-frame-as-parent-and-not-window/54018499#54018499), I've changed my code of the `MainWindow` to this:

> The code on the `MainWindow` must be this:
>
> ```xml
> <!-- Opening Window tag with all attributes -->
> <Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
> <!-- Closing Window tag -->
> ```
>
> This will also show the `StartScreenPage` on the window.

However the null reference error is still being thrown.

Comment: there is no start GRID element in startScreenPage.xaml ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari: No adding the grid didn't anything to the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little null checking in your code, which is where this is happening.

The best way to find the issue is to go to the Visual Studio tool panel

**Debug → Windows → Exception Settings**

and fully check the row labelled '`Common Language Runtime Exceptions`'. When you run the code again, you should get more information about where the null exception is happening.