# Page can have only Frame as parent and not Window

Tags: wpf, xaml, invalidoperationexception

Continuing on this question: [Null reference error in `App.xaml` MVVM light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008872/null-reference-error-in-app-xaml-mvvm-light), I'm making a WPF application and I'll add a `Page`-element on my `Window`.  For this I'm using next code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Porject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
        xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Project.Pages"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{StaticResource appvm}"
        Title="Project" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Page Content="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Window>
```

However, this gives my this exception:

> `InvalidOperationException`: `Page` can have only `Window` or `Frame` as parent.

So you can see in the first code block the parent of the `Page` is a `Window`. If I place the `Page`-element in a `Frame` *(like code below)*, the exception doesn't throw.

```xml
<!-- Opening Window tag with all attributes -->
<Frame>
    <Frame.Content>
        <Page Content="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
<!-- Closing Window tag -->
```

So you can see, the `Page`-element can only have a `Frame` as parent. But why says the exception *"… only a `Window` **or** `Frame` as parent"*? Must it be this:

> `InvalidOperationException`: `Page` can have only <strike>`Window` or</strike> `Frame` as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the code on the `MainWindow` must be this:

```xml
<!-- Opening Window tag with all attributes -->
<Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<!-- Closing Window tag -->
```

This will also show the `StartScreenPage` on the window.